# Excel VBA check if file exists with a twist

Tags: vba, excel, file-exists

It is hard to be specific and short in this topic, but I try my best:

Let's say we have a folder on a specific location where we get files with names for example let's use x1; x2; x3, etc.

Then we have an excel file where we have numbers in a column. ex. 1; 2; 3; etc.

I have written a script that makes it possible to click those numbers so an explorer window will pop up searching for the specific number in the folder.

For example we click the number "2", and an explorer window will pop up with the search result for "2x" in that specific folder.

The script looks like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

Dim c As String
Dim backup As String

c = Target.Range
backup = "~%3D" & Left(c, 7)

    If Left(c, 1) = "C" And Len(c) > 7 And Right(c, 1) = "$" Then 'this part doesn't really matter
    RetVal = Shell("c:\Windows\explorer.exe ""search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results&crumb=System.Generic.String%3A" & backup & "%20kind%3A%3Dfolder&crumb=location:%5C%5Cserver%5Cbackup$", vbNormalFocus)

    End If

End Sub
```

I wonder if it is possible somehow, to find out if there is a file that matches the search or it does not exists. What I mean is, for example if I click on the number "2" in excel, the explorer will pop up and it will show the files which names contain "x2" or it will show "**No items match your search.**"

I would like to return this somehow to excel if we have a search result **or** we don't.
Even a Boolean would do the trick for me.

I can not use the ordinary check like:

```
If Dir(folder) = "" Then
```

because we can have multiple files with the same name and their name contains the date of their creation. ex. x1_02_04_2015 and we can also have an x1_05_11_2014

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following. You don't really need to use any shell functionality

```
     Sub LoopThroughFilesWorkbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
        Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant, myBool As Boolean
        file = Dir("c:\testfolder\")
        Do While file <> ""
            Bool = False
            If InStr(file, "test") > 0 Then ' you can change teh condition here to fit your criteria
               myBool = True
               MsgBox ("Found" & file)
            End If
            file = Dir
        Loop
        If Not myBool Then
            MsgBox ("File not found")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: It is almost perfect! Only problem is that it loops trough all files in the folder and I get the message file not found once for every file

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please let me know if that works for you

Comment: Compile error:
 it says: Exit Do not within Do...Loop

Comment: oops! it has been a long day :(. Fixed it again

Comment: mine as well :) so I took out the "Exit Do" now if I add the name I search for instead of the "test" it pops up a message for every file it found, if I use a variable (target.range) as I should, I get the "File not found" even if the file exists. I feel that we are very close!

Comment: did you change `file = Dir("c:\testfolder\")` to the directory where your files are?

Comment: yes, the script works perfectly, it was my bad. I figured out that the upper case does matter so x is not equal X. I have got tired as well. Thank you very much for the help! I accept the solution!